# How to select only the first cell of every row in a jtable, one at a time while the other cells cant be selected

Tags: java, swing, jtable, row

How can I select only the first cell of every row in a jtable, one at a time while the other cells cant be selected?

My code is:

```
        jTable5.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
          public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){

    int i=jTable5.getSelectedColumn();
    System.out.println(i);
    if(i==0)
    {  
        jTable5.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
         jTable5.getColumnModel().getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

    }
    else{
        jTable5.setCellSelectionEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

});

Still,while moving on the cell of  second column,it first select that cell and then deselect it.

Comment: please try what I have tried coding..Can you please suggest something better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, disable row selection:

```
setRowSelectionAllowed(false);
```

Second, create a SelectionListener, which always move the selection to the first column of row:

```
ListSelectionListener listerner = new ListSelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
          setColumnSelectionInterval(0, 0);
       }
    };
```

And finally add the listener to your table's Column Selection Model

```
getColumnModel().getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(listerner);
```

Comment: Only one problem is I want only one cell to be selected at one time.

Comment: Then set the selection mode to SINGLE_SELECTION, as you did in your code snippet